# Reading and parsing a large .dat file

Tags: parsing, large-data

I am trying to parse a huge .dat file (4gb). I have tried with R but it just takes too long. Is there a way to parse a .dat file by segments, for example every 30000 lines? Any other solutions would also be welcomed.
This is what it looks like:
[image]

These are the first two lines with header:
`ST|ZIPCODE|GEO_ID|GEO_TTL|FOOTID_GEO|NAICS2012|NAICS2012_TTL|FOOTID_NAICS|YEAR|EMPSZES|EMPSZES_TTL|ESTAB|ESTAB_F <br/>
01|35004|8610000US35004|35004(MOODY,AL)||00|Total for all sectors||2012|001|All establishments|167| <br/>
01|35004|8610000US35004|35004(MOODY,AL)||00|Total for all sectors||2012|212|Establishments with 1 to 4 employees|91|`

Comment: What is in your `.dat` file? Can you give a couple of lines for us to know the structure. You can significantly increase R reading speed if you specify the structure.

Comment: Dividing everything up in segments isnt going to solve anything, the dat is and stays 4GB. No matter how you twist or bend it. Sorry for not answering or contributing, but just wanted to point that out

Comment: @EliKorvigo I have added a snippet of the file.

Comment: @Syntasu thank you, now I know my solution is actually not a solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an option to read data faster in R by using the `fread` function in the `data.table` package.

**EDIT**

I removed all `<br/>` new-line tags. This is the edited dataset

```
ST|ZIPCODE|GEO_ID|GEO_TTL|FOOTID_GEO|NAICS2012|NAICS2012_TTL|FOOTID_NAICS|YEAR|EMPSZES|EMPSZES_TTL|ESTAB|ESTAB_F
01|35004|8610000US35004|35004(MOODY,AL)||00|Total for all sectors||2012|001|All establishments|167| 
01|35004|8610000US35004|35004(MOODY,AL)||00|Total for all sectors||2012|212|Establishments with 1 to 4 employees|91|
```

Then I matched variables with classes. You  should use `nrows` ~ 100.

```
colclasses = sapply(read.table(edited_data, nrows=1, sep="|", header=T),class)
```

Then I read the edited data.

```
your_data <- fread(edited_data, sep="|", sep2=NULL, nrows=-1L, header=T, na.strings="NA",
        stringsAsFactors=FALSE, verbose=FALSE, autostart=30L, skip=-1L, select=NULL,
        colClasses=colclasses)
```

Everything worked like a charm. In case you have problems removing the tags, use this simple Python script (it will take some time for sure):

```
original_file = file_path_to_original_file # e.g. "/Users/User/file.dat"
edited_file = file_path_to_new_file # e.g. "/Users/User/file_edited.dat"

with open(original_file) as inp:
    with open(edited_file, "w") as op:
        for line in inp:
            op.write(line.replace("<br/>", "")
```

P.S.

You can use `read.table` with similar optimizations, but it won't give you nearly as much speed.

Comment: `Error in fread("establishments_by_zip.dat", sep = "|", sep2 = NULL, nrows = -1L,  : 
  Column name 'V1' in colClasses[[1]] not found`

I get the following error. I don't quite know what is going wrong. Should I specify column names in advance?

Comment: Give me the first 2 lines of your data set (not a screenshot).

Comment: @peech remove "<br/>" new-line html taggs from all lines. replace them with standard "\n" symbols.

Comment: @peech I've edited my answer so that you could reproduce my actions. I faced no errors.